# Spotify API, can't chain two API calls properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify, es6-promise, fetch-api

I'm having trouble chaining these two API calls. So basically I'm trying to recreate the Spotify interface and individually, these calls actually work which is great!

I also have an 'onPlayClick' function that's basically the same function as 'onNextClick' as seen below, but with a different endpoint and is a PUT method instead of a POST method. That plays and sets the state of selectedSong correctly.

However, onNextClick calling updateCurrentlyPlaying does not work as intended. The intended functionality is that when the user clicks next, the song would go to the next track (which works!), AND THEN updates the track information on the UI.

But what ends up happening is that it FIRST updates the track information AND THEN switches track, so on the UI it's always "one track behind" in a sense and I do not know why the second API is getting ahead of the first one! :S Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
onNextClick = () => {
  const { deviceId, token } = this.state
  fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/next?device_id=${deviceId}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token },
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(this.updateCurrentlyPlaying())  
 }



updateCurrentlyPlaying(){
    const { deviceId, token } = this.state;

    let selectedSong;
    fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing?device_id=${deviceId}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      selectedSong = {
        name: data.item.name,
        duration: Math.round(data.item.duration_ms / 1000),
        artists: data.item.artists,
        album: data.item.album.name,
        image: data.item.album.images[0],
        id: data.item.id,
        uri: data.item.uri,
        offset: data.offset
      }
      this.setState({ selectedSong })
    })
  }
```

Comment: Why is the first `then` async?

Comment: Sorry, edited. It's been a really long day with this issue.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong with how I do my fetches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated Answer

As discussed below, the original answer below is probably still relevant. However the first problem is the way `this.updateCurrentlyPlaying` is invoked. In writing `.then(this.updateCurrentlyPlaying())`, you are immediately invoking `this.updateCurrentlyPlaying`, which is passing `undefined` back into the Promise chain.

Instead, you want something like:

```js
onNextClick = () => {
  const { deviceId, token } = this.state
  fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/next?device_id=${deviceId}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token },
  })
  .then(() => this.updateCurrentlyPlaying()) 
 }
```

### Original Answer

My guess is that your code is fine, but Spotify isn't behaving the way you would expect it to. When you POST to `me/player/next`, the endpoint immediately responds code 204 indicating that it received your request.

Indeed, that is what the [Spotify API docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/skip-users-playback-to-next-track/) say:

> A completed request will return a 204 NO CONTENT response code, and then issue the command to the player.

This means that your code sees the 204 and immediately goes on to call the Spotify API for the current track. This occurs **before** the passed `command to the player` noted above has been invoked by Spotify's player.

I'm not very familiar with the Spotify API and I see this is in Beta - maybe they will provide a more elegant solution in the near future. Until then, your best bet might be to retry the second call (with a timeout limit) a few times until you confirm that the track has indeed changed.

Here's a quick example how you might implement that:

```js
  updateCurrentlyPlaying(priorSongId) {
    const {deviceId, token} = this.state;

    let selectedSong;
    let numTries = 0;
    const retryFetchUntilUpdate = () => {
      fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing?device_id=${deviceId}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token},
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          if (data.item.id === priorSongId && numTries < 5) {
            numTries += 1;
            setTimeout(retryFetchUntilUpdate, 250)
          } else {
            selectedSong = {
              name: data.item.name,
              duration: Math.round(data.item.duration_ms / 1000),
              artists: data.item.artists,
              album: data.item.album.name,
              image: data.item.album.images[0],
              id: data.item.id,
              uri: data.item.uri,
              offset: data.offset
            }
            this.setState({selectedSong})
          }
        })
    }
    retryFetchUntilUpdate();
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The POST to me/player/next happening immediately would actually be exactly what I want, but it's not happening.

It's actually the GET from updateCurrentlyPlaying that executes first, and I have no idea why

Comment: How do you know the GET is executing first? My suspicion is that it is executing second, but the song isn't yet updated on Spotify's end.

Comment: Scratch that, just took another look: have you tried removing the () from `.then(this.updateCurrentlyPlaying())`? As is, it will invoke `updateCurrentlyPlaying` and pass its **result** (`undefined` in this case) to the promise chain.

Comment: I have actually! But what ends up happening after that is that the track information doesn't get updated at all because it never gets into updateCurrentlyPlaying! I put a console log at the beginning of it to see if it gets reached and it does not.. I tried binding and changing updateCurrentlyPlaying to a fat arrow function but that did not work either

Comment: That's odd. And no errors? Try: `.then(() => this.updateCurrentlyPlaying())`.

--EDIT: Just saw your edit. What about removing `.then(response => response.json())` and replacing with `.then(() => this.updateCurrentlyPlaying())`?

Comment: Same deal, tried it without the smooth parenthesis and wit. Just read your edit, trying it now

Comment: And when you do my last suggestion + add a console.log to `updateCurrentlyPlaying`, it never gets called?

Comment: Just did your last suggestion and it reaches it now. But I'm now back at the original issue where the track data is lagging behind by one so to speak

Comment: Ok, I think my original answer (regarding Spotify itself lagging behind) might help with this problem. Try the suggested retry fetch code

Comment: Okay, that worked! I cut out the comparison to the old song because I actually technically dont have that in state. That's so there aren't any additional tries once its found correct?

Comment: Great! That's correct. If you omit the prior ID check, it'll still work, just not micro-optimized since you'll end up making unnecessary calls to the API. You could opt to either 1) start storing that song ID or 2) break the retry loop if the song ID changes while the loop is going on. First option would be more robust (e.g. what if the user clicks the button several times quickly?).

Comment: That's true, though I'm also trying to make this function for the previous button as well which also runs through the update method. I'll have to spend some time at the drawing board a bit.

But thank you so much! I spent a whole day and a half on this!

Comment: Sorry I just had one more thought.. that previous song check that you had suggested would actually work even if previous/next shared this same function won't it?

Comment: Yup, it would work both ways since the intent is just to confirm that it has changed

Comment: Fair! Cheers, bud!